# Vetor com ponteiros ordenados em ordem crescente em C

Tags: c

Estou com dificuldade de ordenar em ordem crescente os valores presentes em um vetor usando ponteiros, eu testei e o problema é que ele apenas mostra o vetor com a sequencia digitada inversa, e não em ordem crescente, segue o código para análise:

```
int main(void){

    int vec[5] = {},aux; // Vetor e aux pra ordernar
    int *p; // ponteiro para o vetor

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ // obter o vetor do usuario
        printf("Digite o elemento de numero %d do vetor: ", i+1);
        scanf_s("%d",&vec[i]);
    }
    p = &vec[0]; // Ponteiro no primeiro elemento do vetor

            for (int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop de scaneamento do vetor
            {
                for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
                {
                    if ((p+i)>(p+j)) // Ordena o vetor atravez dos ponteiros
                    {
                        aux = *(p+i);
                        *(p+i) = *(p+j);
                        *(p+j) = aux;
                    }
                }
            }
    printf("\n\nSeu vetor ordenado: ["); // print do vetor ordenado
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf(" %d ",vec[i]);
    }
    printf("]");
    return 0;


}
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar para deixar ele em ordem crescente, utilizando os ponteiros para navegar pelo vetor? Obrigado.

Comment: Será que você não deveria comparar o conteúdo dos endereços e não os próprios endereços?

Comment: Eu estou começando agora com ponteiros,então não estou familiarizado com isso,poderia me explicar um pouco? onde eu deveria comparar e como

Comment: Aqui `if ((p+i)>(p+j))` você está comparando dois endereços e não dois inteiros.

Comment: Estou comparando dois ponteiros,que são os pedidos pelo enunciado em questão ''ponteiros para navegar no vetor'',o problema seria,eles estão então recebendo os valores mas não vão fazer a forma crescente,correto?

Comment: Mas você quer ordenar os endereços ou os valores contidos nestes endereços? Não faz muito sentido ordenar os ponteiros já que não interessa o valor destes ponteiros mas sim os valores que eles apontam.

Comment: Eu tenho que ordenar os valores inseridos nos vetores,em forma crescente,vou mandar o enunciado

Comment: Escreva um programa que leia 5 inteiros e os armazene em um vetor. A partir disso,
utilizando ponteiros para navegar no vetor, os valores armazenados no vetor devem
ordenados do menor para o maior. O vetor ordenado deve ser apresentado na tela.

Comment: Troque seu trecho de código da troca por: `for (int i=0;i<4;i++) { for (int j=i+1;j<5;j++) { if (*(p+i) > *(p+j)) { aux = *(p+i); *(p+i) = *(p+j); *(p+j) = aux; } } }`

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma função para fazer essa ordenação, dessa forma você vai estar trabalhando com ponteiros automaticamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void ordenar(int *vetor, size_t tamanho);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vetor[5] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4};

    ordenar(vetor, 5);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void ordenar(int *vetor, size_t tamanho) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < tamanho; ++j) {
            if (vetor[i] > vetor[j]) {
                int temp = vetor[i];
                vetor[i] = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Faltou criar a função para imprimir os elementos do vetor, mas o código foi testado e está funcionando.

Comment: Muito obrigado,eu vou fazer aqui,valeu mesmo,tava sofrendo kk

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo mais simples usando a função `qsort` da biblioteca padrão:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compara(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int vetor[5] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4};

    qsort(vetor, 5, sizeof(int), compara);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d ", vetor[i]);

    return 0;
}
```